# Problema em instrução SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema em meu código *SQL*. Bom, tenho esta função que se encontra na classe `Usuario`:

```
public function CS_GetUsuarios($sql_aux = false)
{
    global $objConexao;

    $strSql =   "SELECT U.*, A.*, G.*,
                (
                SELECT COALESCE(SUM(V.countView), 0) FROM usuario_visitas V WHERE V.codUsuario = U.codUsuario
                ) as total_visitas,
                (
                SELECT COALESCE(SUM(F.countVotos), 0) FROM usuario_votos F WHERE F.codUsuario = U.codUsuario
                ) as total_votos
                FROM usuario U
                LEFT JOIN usuario_visitas A ON U.codUsuario = A.codUsuario
                LEFT JOIN usuario_fotos G ON G.cod_usuario = U.codUsuario
                WHERE U.indAtivo = 'S' AND G.indExibir = 'S'
                $sql_aux";

    $vetDados = $objConexao->query($strSql)->fetchAll();
    return $vetDados;
}
```

E no index estou chamando o mesmo:

`$vet_dados_top = Usuario::CS_GetUsuarios("AND U.tipo_conta = '1' GROUP BY U.codUsuario ORDER BY total_visitas DESC LIMIT 12");`

Pois bem, meu problema está sendo que, ele só me retorna os dados **completos** dos usuários que possuem visitas (registro) na tabela `usuario_visitas`. Quando o usuário não recebeu nenhum visitante no perfil ele retorna especificamente o `codUsuario = null`, sendo que, em minha lógica, eu programei para ele trazer todos os registros, mesmo daqueles usuários que não possuem nenhuma visita.

Dando um `var_dump()` em `$vet_dados_top` o resultado é mais ou menos este:

Usuário que possui visita

> ```
> array (size=121)
>   'codUsuario' => string '1182652231' (length=10)
>   0 => string '1182652231' (length=10)
>   'strLogin' => string 'fulano' (length=7)
>   1 => string 'fulano' (length=7)
>   'strSenha' => string 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX' (length=32)
>   2 => string 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX' (length=32)
>   [...]
> ```

Usuário que não possui visitas

> ```
> array (size=121)
>   'codUsuario' => null
>   0 => string '1182652232' (length=10)
>   'strLogin' => string 'ciclano' (length=5)
>   1 => string 'ciclano' (length=5)
>   'strSenha' => string 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' (length=32)
>   2 => string 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' (length=32)
>   [...]
> ```

A tabela `usuario_visitas` não possui os códigos de todos os usuários, apenas os que foram visitados. Visitou, foi adicionado à tabela.

Onde estou errando no pensamento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No where, você coloca a clausula da tabela G.

Altere também a ordem do `coalesce`, dentro do `Sum()`.

e ao passar os parâmetros, não informe o group by, não há nenhuma função de agregação na query para ser agrupado.

Tente fazer o seguinte:

```
"SELECT U.*, A.*, G.*, U.codUsuario as codigoUsuario,
            (
            SELECT SUM(COALESCE(V.countView, 0)) FROM usuario_visitas V WHERE V.codUsuario = U.codUsuario
            ) as total_visitas,
            (
            SELECT SUM(COALESCE(F.countVotos, 0)) FROM usuario_votos F WHERE F.codUsuario = U.codUsuario
            ) as total_votos
            FROM usuario U
            LEFT JOIN usuario_visitas A ON U.codUsuario = A.codUsuario
            LEFT JOIN usuario_fotos G ON G.cod_usuario = U.codUsuario AND G.indExibir = 'S'
            WHERE U.indAtivo = 'S' 
            $sql_aux";
```

Adicionei mais uma coluna buscando o valor de U.codUsuario e renomeando para codigoUsuario, no seu php, busque pelo valor de codigoUsuario e veja se está correto

Comment: Rovann, não deu certo. Mesma coisa do Motta, continua trazendo o `codUsuario = null` do usuário que não possui visitas.

Comment: repare se a coluna codUsuario é da tabela A ou U, pois ambas estão com o mesmo nome

Comment: alterei a parte dos Coalesce tb, apesar de não influenciar na questão, mas faz diferença no sum

Comment: acredito que não precise do group by também, talvez um distinct

Comment: Continuou na mesma, eu fiz uma edição na minha pergunta original. Onde eu cito que a tabela `usuario_visitas` não possui todos os códigos de usuário, tem alguma relação com o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Bom, se eu literalmente retirar o * da tabela não funciona. Fiz assim `SELECT U.*, G.*,` funcionou como deveria. Mas o que estava acontecendo, afinal?

Comment: a tabela A também tem uma coluna de nome codUsuario, e ela sempre virá como null quando não houver visitas, acredito que você estava pegando o valor dela

Comment: coloquei mais uma alteração que pode te ajudar

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado! Tu é do meu estado, de Colatina hehe, sou de Vitória. Abraço!

Comment: Isso! rsrs por nada e abraços

Answer (score 0):

```
...
"SELECT U.*, A.*, G.*,
                (
                SELECT COALESCE(SUM(V.countView), 0) FROM usuario_visitas V WHERE V.codUsuario = U.codUsuario
                ) as total_visitas,
                (
                SELECT COALESCE(SUM(F.countVotos), 0) FROM usuario_votos F WHERE F.codUsuario = U.codUsuario
                ) as total_votos
                FROM usuario U
                LEFT JOIN usuario_visitas A ON U.codUsuario = A.codUsuario
                LEFT JOIN usuario_fotos G ON G.cod_usuario = U.codUsuario
                      AND G.indExibir = 'S'     
                WHERE U.indAtivo = 'S'
                $sql_aux";
...
```

Comment: Não deu certo, continua trazendo o `codUsuario = null` do usuário que não possui visitas.

Comment: O u.codUsuario  deveria trazer o g.codUsuario  não